# How to merge hashes if a specified key's values are same in a array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a array of hashes like this:

```
[ {:foo=>2, :date=>Sat, 01 Sep 2014},
 {:foo2=>2, :date=>Sat, 02 Sep 2014},
 {:foo3=>3, :date=>Sat, 01 Sep 2014},
 {:foo4=>4, :date=>Sat, 03 Sep 2014},
  {:foo5=>5, :date=>Sat, 02 Sep 2014}]
```

And I want to merge hashes if the `:date` are same.
What I expect from the array above is:

```
[ {:foo=>2, :foo3=>3, :date=>Sat, 01 Sep 2014},
 {:foo2=>2, :foo5=>5 :date=>Sat, 02 Sep 2014},
 {:foo4=>4, :date=>Sat, 03 Sep 2014}]
```

How can I do it?

Maybe should I reconsider data structure itself? For example should I use `date` value as a key of hash?

Comment: No, it's `Date` class. why?

Comment: Your hash definitions aren't valid. It's important that they be reusable when we try to help you, so make sure that Ruby will accept them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you could do it in a line ([demo](http://ideone.com/FQykjw)):

```
hashes.group_by{|h| h[:date] }.map{|_, hs| hs.reduce(:merge)}
```

This code does the following:

- groups all hashes by their `:date` value
- for each `:date` group, takes all hashes in it and merges them all into one hash

***EDIT:*** Applied modifications suggested by tokland and Cary Swoveland. Thanks!

Comment: nit-picking: `hashes.group_by { |h| h[:date] }.map { |k, hs| hs.reduce(:merge) }`

Comment: Nice solution. You might consider `|_,hs|` to tell the reader you're not using the key in the block. It's a pretty small block, so that may be obvious, but still...

Comment: Little gotcha - If :date isn't a symbol use 'date'

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that uses a block to resolve the values of keys that are contained in both of the hashes being merged.

```
arr = [ {:foo=>2, :date=>'Sat, 01 Sep 2014'},
        {:foo2=>2, :date=>'Sat, 02 Sep 2014'},
        {:foo3=>3, :date=>'Sat, 01 Sep 2014'},
        {:foo4=>4, :date=>'Sat, 03 Sep 2014'},
        {:foo5=>5, :date=>'Sat, 02 Sep 2014'}]

arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update({ g[:date]=>g }) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
end.values
  #=> [{:foo=>2,  :date=>"Sat, 01 Sep 2014", :foo3=>3},
  #    {:foo2=>2, :date=>"Sat, 02 Sep 2014", :foo5=>5},
  #    {:foo4=>4, :date=>"Sat, 03 Sep 2014"}]
```

I've used a placeholder `_` for the block variable containing the value of the key since it it not used in the block.